Names of Characters in Mahabharata
I've been reading the Mahabharata for a few days now and I've noticed that the characters don't have 1, 2 or even 10 names.
They have, like for example the sun god 108 names.
Is there a deeper meaning to giving a lot of names to the characters/gods?
Or is this a quirk of that time / writing style

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's because most of them are residents of Svarga who temporarily descended to bhuloka, so the appropritate glorification in the Mahabharata.
